# How to insert multi records to database by auto generate row on click button in C#

Tags: c#

I want to generate new record on 'add' button click.then after insert ten records or morethan it then insert these records into databse..how to do this ..
I can only create new records like in below code but want to insert these records in database at once after click submit button.

```
private int numOfRows = 1;
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                GenerateTable(numOfRows);
            }
        }
        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (ViewState["RowsCount"] != null)
            {
                numOfRows = Convert.ToInt32(ViewState["RowsCount"].ToString());
                GenerateTable(numOfRows);
            }
        }
        private void SetPreviousData(int rowsCount, int colsCount)
        {
            Table table = (Table)Page.FindControl("Table1");
            if (table != null)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < rowsCount; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < colsCount; j++)
                    {
                        TextBox tb = (TextBox)table.Rows[i].Cells[j].FindControl("TextBoxRow_" + i + "Col_" + j);
                        tb.Text = Request.Form["TextBoxRow_" + i + "Col_" + j];
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        private void GenerateTable(int rowsCount)
        {
            Table table = new Table();
            table.ID = "Table1";
            Page.Form.Controls.Add(table);
            const int colsCount = 3;
            for (int i = 0; i < rowsCount; i++)
            {
                TableRow row = new TableRow();
                for (int j = 0; j < colsCount; j++)
                {
                    TableCell cell = new TableCell();
                    TextBox tb = new TextBox();
                    tb.ID = "TextBoxRow_" + i + "Col_" + j;
                    cell.Controls.Add(tb);
                    row.Cells.Add(cell);
                }
                table.Rows.Add(row);
            }
            SetPreviousData(rowsCount, colsCount);
            rowsCount++;
            ViewState["RowsCount"] = rowsCount;
        }
```

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: show us your code and table structure..then only anybody can help you.

Comment: Please read [FAQ] and [ask] couple of times..

Comment: check my updated quession.

Answer (score 2):

First generate onClick() event on button, 
stepwise code: database connection,table insert commands.